# How to assign a different ID to every auto-generated button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use Facebook API to get all groups from user and then another function with FQL to make a different div for each group, and assign to each div a button, which links to another page, something like:

```
$('.groupButton').click(function() {  
  window.location ='anotherpage.html?groupid=' + groupid;
});
```

But on every button it assigns the last button's groupid.
I don't know where's the mistake.

The 2 functions:

```
        function getGroupsIds(){
            document.getElementById('content_text').innerHTML = "";
            FB.api('/me/groups',function(resp){
                for (var i=0, l=resp.data.length; i<l; i++){ 
                getGroupInfo(resp.data[i].id);
                }
            });
        }


        function getGroupInfo(groupid){
            FB.api({
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: 'Select name, description, gid, pic_cover from group where gid=' + groupid
            }, function(resp){
                var content_text = document.getElementById('content_text');
                var group = new Array(); 
                for (var i=0, l=resp.length; i<l; i++) 
                {


                    groupinput = document.createElement('button');
                    groupinput.className = "groupButton";            
                    groupinput.innerHTML = "Vizualise";

                    $('.groupButton').click(function() {  
                    window.location ='pages/appviz.html?groupid=' + groupid;
                    });


                    groupdiv.appendChild(groupinput);
                    content_text.appendChild(groupdiv);

                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Where are you defining `groupid`?

Comment: I have 2 functions, the first one where i get the ID's of the groups, and another one, which i call in the first one, with the ID i just got. So groupid is a function variable.

Comment: Perhaps you could add the essentials of those two functions to your question. If the `groupid` is not behaving as expected - we need to have a look at how you are generating it. :)

Comment: Nice job on adding more of the code! Any reason why you're not using jQuery for the rest of your script?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with jQuery, and I don't have the time to start learn it from scratch.

Comment: So, any ideas? I don't really get why it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i used javascript, and it worked.

```
 groupinput.onclick = function(){ window.location.replace('pages/appviz.html?groupid=' + groupid);};
```

Answer (score 1):

From where you get the groupid? It is not clear. You can assign the groupid in the button as id. Then get the value when you click the button.

```
$('.groupButton').click(function() {
groupid = this.id;
window.location ='anotherpage.html?groupid=' + groupid;
});
```

And the input will be like

```
<input type='button' id='1' value='Profile' class='groupButton' />
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: or if `group_id` isn't used elsewhere, save a few milliseconds by dropping it and using `window.location ='anotherpage.html?groupid=' + this.id;`

Comment: :) yeah, I just didn't change his one, just add my line there. :)

Comment: I gotta raise my eyebrow at the "number only" id attribute... While it might very well be perfectly valid, I wouldn't really like to see that in code I'm working on. Just a personal preference perhaps...

Comment: This was example, can use any character before the number. This is what I told the technique. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning the click handler repeatedly in the for loop. This is causing the all buttons with the `groupButton` class to navigate to the last `groupid` you processed in the loop.

```
for (var i=0, l=resp.length; i<l; i++) {
    // this gets reassigned resp.length times
    $('.groupButton').click(function() {
        window.location ='pages/appviz.html?groupid=' + groupid;
    }
}
```

What you probably want is

```
function getGroupInfo(groupid){
    FB.api({
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'Select name, description, gid, pic_cover from group where gid=' + groupid
    },
    function(resp) {
        ...
        for() { ... }

        groupdiv.appendChild(groupinput);
        content_text.appendChild(groupdiv);

        // assign click handler after building the elements
        $('.groupButton').click(function() {
            window.location = 'pages/appviz.html?groupid=' + this.id;
        });
    }
```

The `$('.groupButton')` is the set of all elements with the `groupButton` class (see [Class Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)). So you need `this.id` to get the `id` of the instance of button you clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably just remove the following code from inside of loop

```
 $('.groupButton').click(function() {  
                window.location ='pages/appviz.html?groupid=' + groupid;
                });
```

And put it outside of the function `function getGroupInfo(groupid)`, because the click function is only to done the action. Try and let us know its worked or not.

```
function getGroupInfo(groupid){
            FB.api({
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: 'Select name, description, gid, pic_cover from group where gid=' + groupid
            }, function(resp){
                var content_text = document.getElementById('content_text');
                var group = new Array(); 
                for (var i=0, l=resp.length; i<l; i++) 
                {


                    groupinput = document.createElement('button');
                    groupinput.className = "groupButton";            
                    groupinput.innerHTML = "Vizualise";
                    groupinput.id = "g"+groupid;

                    groupdiv.appendChild(groupinput);
                    content_text.appendChild(groupdiv);

                }
            });
    }

$('.groupButton').click(function() {  
groupid = this.id;
 window.location ='pages/appviz.html?groupid=' + groupid.substr(1);
});
```

Try this